# Change two independent routes at the same time - Can this be done with Auxillary routing?

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

By Auxilary routing we can make two independent routing in same component. By using same concept for a single URL, can we change the independent routes same time?

for example:

1. http://localhost:4200/listing  for this route, I want to load C1 Component against name routing-outlet and listing component from my main routing-outlet.
2. http://localhost:4200/listings for this route, I want to load C2 Component against name routing-outlet and listings component from my main routing-outlet.

   ```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
       { path: '', component: HeroComponent, outlet: 'hero', children: [
       { path: 'listings', component: C2Component},
       { path: 'listing', component: C1Component},]},

       { path: '', component: ContentComponent, children: [
       { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
       { path: 'listings', component: ListingsComponent},
       { path: 'listing', component: ListingComponent},
       { path: 'sellers', component: SellersComponent},
       { path: 'seller', component: SellerComponent}]}];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
    { path: 'listing', component: C1Component, outlet:'hero'},
    { path: 'listing', component: ListingComponent},
    { path: 'listings', component: C2Component, outlet:'hero'},
    { path: 'listings', component: ListingsComponent},
```

As per the routing the same route has two config so the outlet with name hero will get C1Component and the main router-outlet will get Listing Component

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HeroComponent, outlet: 'hero'},

    { path: 'listing', component: C1Component, outlet:'hero'},
    { path: 'listing', component: ListingComponent},
    { path: 'listings', component: C2Component, outlet:'hero'},
    { path: 'listings', component: ListingsComponent},

    { path: '', component: ContentComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent} 
    { path: 'sellers', component: SellersComponent},
    { path: 'seller', component: SellerComponent}]
}];
```